# Secure way to output encoding HTML for insert raw html via javascript

Tags: xss, javascript, html, json, dom

I want to be 100% secure, I create raw html this way:

```
const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = html_raw
const cloned = template.content.cloneNode(true)

document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(cloned);
```

When I build the html I insert independently every string to his respective  html element (from json data object) who pass the validation function

In the validation function, I white list this characters: `a-z0123456789(),.:-_/@%'space`
obviously a space is

after validate the string I replace this characters `(),.:-_/@%'space` to HTML encoding, for example `(` equal to `&#40;`

my question is, **is secure HTML encoding in this way, inserting via innerHTML from html_raw related to HTML context (xss attack)?**

I saw this question about innerHTML script can not be executed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

I bypass innerHTML with: `<img src="" onerror=alert(0)>` but if I replace with HTML encoding: `&lt;img src=&quot;&quot; onerror=alert(0)&gt;` does not execute the script

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert untrusted HTML markup as text, then you should use the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), **not** `innerHTML`. The `textContent` property reliably prevents XSS attacks, because the content is only rendered as text and never interpreted as HTML markup, regardless of special characters like `<` and `>`.

Trying to come up with your own HTML filters is generally a bad idea, because there's a huge risk of getting this wrong. In your example, you show that angled brackets and double quotes are converted into HTML entities, but your list does not include those characters -- so that's already a mistake either in your list or your description.

If you want to be sure, use the (correct) features provided by the browser itself.

Comment: Hi, I already used textContent inside the build html, I think you can not escape single quota with textContent, do you know another way to insert raw html securely ?, because textContent is for text. By the way I have a whitelist no Blacklist so -- does not matter.

Comment: you might look into using a sandboxed iframe: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Comment: @Thenothing: You say you already use `textContent` when you build HTML elements (with JavaScript, obviously). Then you shouldn't need `innerHTML` *at all*. Building HTML with JavaScript means you get `Node` objects which can be inserted directly into the document through methods like `Node.appendChild()`. The `innerHTML` is only required if you have a *string* with HTML markup (typically from the server). You don't have to escape anything with `textContent`, because all characters (including single quotes) are treated as literal text and not interpreted as HTML markup.

Comment: @Thenothing: It does matter whether or not your whitelist is complete. If it's incomplete, you're blocking characters which shouldn't be blocked. This may not lead to XSS vulnerabilities, but it's a bug which can definitely cause problems.

Comment: @browsermator: I'm not sure what this has to do with the question.

Comment: wasn't sure if they wanted HTML to be read as markup or just displayed as text.  But if they wanted HTML to be interpreted, but safely, the sandboxed iframe is an alternative.